# Finding integer divisors of a set of numbers in C language

Tags: c, function, if-statement, math

I want to do this in a function: How do I find out in a C program if a number is divisible by 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 25 and 125 *without using the % operator and using the divisibility rules? the base should be 10**

Comment: This will be helpful: `a % b == a - (a / b * b)` for positive integers `a` and `b`.

Comment: it's possible using bitwise operations and [modular multiplicative inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse)

Comment: How do you do that with using `%` operator?

Comment: what is the range of divident? like 0-10000?

Comment: yes, the range should be between 0 and 10000

Comment: @tstanisl that was impressive.

Comment: it may be problematic because "divisiblity rule by 3" requires checking if the sum of digits is divisible by 3. Does "no %" rule apply this this last check as well?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Integer division algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5097383/integer-division-algorithm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use **divisibility rules**, you have to work with digits. Perhaps task assumes no division (at least in explicit form - you can extract digits from string representation)

For divisibility by **2**, check whether the last digit is in set `0,2,4,6,8`

For divisibility by **4**, check whether the last digit + doubled previous one is in set `0,4,8`. If result is larger than 10, repeat (`88=>2*8+8=24=>2*2+4=8`)

Similar situation for **8**, but sum `last + 2*previous + 4*second_from_the_end` (`512 => 4*5+2*1+2=24=>2*2+4=8`)

For divisibility by **5**, check whether the last digit is in set `0,5`, similar situation for **25**, **125**

For divisibility by **3**, sum all digits, repeat process until result becomes < 10. So-called "digit root" should be in set `0,3,6,9`, similar situation for divisibility by **9**.

For **6** check divisibilty by both **2** and by **3**

I am not strong in C, so my example perhaps is very weird ([ideone check](https://ideone.com/j65cMv))

```
#include <stdio.h>

int divby3(int n) {
    char s[10];
    do {
       sprintf(s, "%d", n);  //transform 72 to char buffer "72"
       n = 0;
       int i = 0;
       while(s[i])  //until nil (end of string) found, we can also use for loop
           n += s[i++] - 0x30;  //get difference of current char and char "0"
           
    }
    while (n >= 10);    //until 1-digit value
    
    return (n==0) || (n==3) || (n==6) || (n==9);
}

int divby5(int n) {
   char s[10];
   int len = sprintf(s, "%d", n);
   n = s[len - 1] - 0x30;  //last digit
   return (n==0) || (n==5);
}

int main(void) {
    printf("%d", divby3(72));  //try 71
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what librarys do i have to include?

Comment: No libraries at all

Comment: how do i find out the last digit?(With code)

Comment: Would you please explain this code with commands? Thank you, it works

Comment: Added some comments

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

A function that uses the `a - (a / b * b)` implementation of the modulus operator: (credit @MikeCat)

```
bool isDivisible(int a, int b)
{
    if((a - (a / b * b)) == 0) return true;
    return false;
}
```

Usage:

```
int main(void)
{  
    int a = 8;
    int b = 4;
    int c = 3;
    
    bool res = isDivisible(a,b);
    bool res2 = isDivisible(a,c);
    
    return 0;
}
```

***EDIT*** - to address question in comments:
*"how can i represent such a program with the divisibility rules? Thank you for your code, i forgott to mention that i have to use the divisibility rules in each function"*

The following shows how to pass in divisibility rules as an argument...

```
const int div_1[] = {2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 25, 125};
const int div_2[] = {7, 5, 17, 12, 11};

int main()
{   
    size_t size = 0;
        
    size = sizeof div_1/sizeof div_1[0];
    bool res = isDivisible(2*3*4*5*6*8*9*25*125, div_1, size);
    size = sizeof div_2/sizeof div_2[0];
    bool res2 = isDivisible(125, div_2, size);
    
    return 0;
}
//              numerator   divisor array    array size
bool isDivisible(long a, long div_rules[], size_t size)
{
    //divisibility rules
    const int divisors[] = {2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 25, 125};
    
    for(int i = 0; i<size;i++)
    {
        if((a - (a / div_rules[i] * div_rules[i])) != 0) return false;
    }
     return true;
}
```

Comment: how can i represent such a program with the divisibility rules? Thank you for your code, i forgott to mention that i have to use the divisibility rules in each function

Comment: @Fennix900, please add this information to the question. Add information about the range and that the base is 10.

Comment: @Fennix900 - Let me know specifics whether or not this implementation (See _EDIT_) works for you.

Comment: @Fennix900 - _"it doesn't work"_ doesn't work either.  with specifics I may be able to address the problem.

Comment: @ryyker Don't worry, MBo already finished this guy's homework for him.

Comment: @SteveSummit - LOL, well, I have to admit that the concept of _divisibility rules_ is a little vague for me, so for all I know I totally missed the point and MBo got it right.  Good for the both of them. :)